# Normalized MySQL database not updating

Tags: mysql

**What I want to do:**

I have a normalized database containing 3 tables. All I want to do is replace all the `MODEL` values with the `SERIES` values where the `OEMID` equals 8.

I've taken 5 rows from each table as an example:

**Series Table**

```
+--------+----------+
| series | seriesid |
+--------+----------+
| 1001   |        7 |
| 10036  |        8 |
| 10067  |        9 |
| 1007   |       10 |
| 10076  |       11 |
+--------+----------+
```

**Model Table**

```
+---------+----------------------------------------+
| ModelId | Model                                  |
+---------+----------------------------------------+
|    6694 | 1001 - 71 Flexi Unit Planter - 30Aug01 |
|    8264 | 10036 - 315SJ Backhoe Loader           |
|    8263 | 10067 - 310J Backhoe Loader - 20Jul17  |
|    6693 | 1007 - 60 Lawn Tractor - 30Aug01       |
|    8262 | 10076 - 853JH Tracked Harvester        |
+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

**Masterdata Table**

```
+------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+------+-------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| partnumber | partname | description | imageurl                     | qty  | oemid | seriesid | modelid | functiongroupid | assemblynameid |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+------+-------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| A32        | Lens     | RED         | AP3415_________UN01JAN94.gif | 2    |     8 |        7 |    6694 |           12318 |         449980 |
| 14274      | Nut      | M10         | TX1061736______UN20JUL09.gif | 1    |     8 |        8 |    8264 |           13996 |         884056 |
| C1115      | HC       | NLA ORDER   | 0000897883____________A2.gif | 1    |     8 |        9 |    8263 |           13962 |         880092 |
| 03H1626    | BOLT     | 1/4 X 1/2   | M5004__________UN02JAN94.gif | 1    |     8 |       10 |    6693 |           17549 |          89782 |
| 1854       | Screw    | M10 X 80    | TX1030795______UN25OCT07.gif | 4    |     8 |       11 |    8262 |           14029 |         891643 |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+------+-------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
```

So lets take the first row in the masterdata table. I want to replace the series `1001` with `1001 - 71 Flexi Unit Planter - 30Aug01`

**What I've Tried:**

The first thing I tried was:

1. Inserting all distinct models into the series table where the oemid=8

   ```
   INSERT INTO SERIES(SERIES) SELECT DISTINCT M.MODEL FROM MASTERDATA MD JOIN MD.MODELID=M.MODELID WHERE MD.OEMID=8;
   ```
2. Since the `SERIESID` column is auto-incrementing, I didn't need to manually set the id. I then attempted to update the `MASTERDATA` table to reflect this change:

   ```
   UPDATE MASTERDATA MD JOIN MODEL M ON M.MODELID=MD.MODELID JOIN SERIES S ON S.SERIES=M.MODEL SET MD.SERIESID=S.SERIESID WHERE MD.OEMID=8;
   ```

The idea for this query is that the `MODEL` table is joined to the `MASTERDATA` table using `MODELID` since I'm not changing any `MODEL` values. Then, I join the `SERIES` table on the `MODEL` table where the `MODEL` is equal to `SERIES`. This will let me get the `SERIESID` for each `MODEL`. Then I simply set the `SERIESID` in `MASTERDATA` to the `SERIESID` in the `SERIES` table. However, this did not work when I ran it.

My only remaining option is to write an external program to deal with this, but I'd prefer not to take this route if possible. Can anyone offer a solution?

Not sure if it matters, but I'm running the DB on Linux CentOS 7.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

This is what the `SERIES` table looks like after inserting the `MODEL` values:

```
+----------------------------------------+-----------+
| series                                 | seriesid  |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+
| 1001                                   |         7 |
| 10036                                  |         8 |
| 10067                                  |         9 |
| 1007                                   |        10 |
| 10076                                  |        11 |
| 1001 - 71 Flexi Unit Planter - 30Aug01 |       256 |
| 10036 - 315SJ Backhoe Loader           |       257 |
| 10067 - 310J Backhoe Loader - 20Jul17  |       258 |
| 1007 - 60 Lawn Tractor - 30Aug01       |       259 |
| 10076 - 853JH Tracked Harvester        |       260 |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

My plan was to use the query you can see above on `2.` then run a query on series to remove any rows where the `SERIESID` doesn't exist in the `MASTERDATA` table.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm aiming for the `MASTERDATA` to look like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+------+-------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| partnumber | partname | description | imageurl                     | qty  | oemid | seriesid   | modelid | functiongroupid | assemblynameid |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+------+-------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| A32        | Lens     | RED         | AP3415_________UN01JAN94.gif | 2    |     8 |        256 |    6694 |           12318 |         449980 |
| 14274      | Nut      | M10         | TX1061736______UN20JUL09.gif | 1    |     8 |        257 |    8264 |           13996 |         884056 |
| C1115      | HC       | NLA ORDER   | 0000897883____________A2.gif | 1    |     8 |        258 |    8263 |           13962 |         880092 |
| 03H1626    | BOLT     | 1/4 X 1/2   | M5004__________UN02JAN94.gif | 1    |     8 |        259 |    6693 |           17549 |          89782 |
| 1854       | Screw    | M10 X 80    | TX1030795______UN25OCT07.gif | 4    |     8 |        260 |    8262 |           14029 |         891643 |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------------------------+------+-------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: the S.SERIES=M.MODEL  condition don't match  ..1001  != 1001 - 71 Flexi Unit Planter - 30Aug01

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes, but I added the model values to the series table, so it should match 1001 - 71 Flexi Unit Planter - 30Aug01 == 1001 - 71 Flexi Unit Planter - 30Aug01. I haven't shown it on my example though. I'll edit the question so you can see.

Comment: let me know when you have update the question  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge It's now updated, see `EDIT:`

Comment: Your edited  question is not clear  ..  1) an updated can't remove rows  from  tables 2) if you remove for SERIES  the rows related  to seriesid that don't match you remove the extended  string inserted  with the insert  .. .. could be that firts you want delete form series  the seriesid that match and second you want update  the master table with the new id  ..  ..

Comment: Could you please give a sample table/data you need as output ?

Comment: I was just stating I'd later run a query to remove the redundant rows from `SERIES`, I didn't mean to imply that UPDATE would remove the rows for me. The DELETE has to be ran after the `MASTERDATA` table is updated else there would be no redundant rows. @JithinScaria I've added the table I'm aiming for, it seems simple, but it just won't work for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this select query below, your requirement is not that clear for me but still hope this will help you some how,

```
select 
   C.partnumber,
   C.partname,
   C.description,
   C.imageurl, 
   C.qty, 
   C.oemid, 
   A.seriesid, 
   B.ModelId, 
   C.functiongroupid, 
   C.assemblynameid 
from 
   Series A, 
   Model B, 
   Masterdata C 
where 
   C.modelid=B.ModelId and 
   A.series = SUBSTRING_INDEX(B.Model,' - ', 1);
```

**Note:**  `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is used assuming first part of the `Model` column in `Model` table is same as the `series` column value in `Series` table. If its directly matching value as you mentioned in **EDIT 1** in question, then we can directly equate.

if above select query gives you the required output, then to update `seriesid` directly in `Masterdata` we can use below update query,

```
update 
   Series A, 
   Model B, 
   Masterdata C 
set 
   C.seriesid = A.seriesid 
where 
   C.modelid=B.ModelId and 
   A.series = SUBSTRING_INDEX(B.Model,' - ', 1);
```

If want to remove the entries other than which matches, then we can use the reverse case of this same where clause, Hope this will be of some help,

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out now. The data is about 100M rows in total (in the `MASTERDATA` table), so it'll take a while to run.

Comment: ok Then try Adding some limit conditions in the inner table selections, like in select query - instead of `Masterdata C` - try with `(select * from Masterdata limit 10000)C` .. this way we can see the logic will be ok or not without waiting much..

Comment: Damn, it just comes back as an empty set.

Comment: oh oh .. I even tried with your dummy data , it worked for me though .. :( now i would suggest, try removing `where` conditions one by one and see the result, try to deduce which condition goes wrong ..

Comment: I removed `and A.series = SUBSTRING_INDEX(B.Model,' - ', 1); ` and managed to get data back

Comment: Actually I think I know what the issue is haha. I restored the DB to before I made the insert into series. So I'll just have to insert that data again into series and your query should work.

Comment: Ohh hapy to hear .. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174219/discussion-between-lucax-and-jithin-scaria).

Comment: Gave this the answer as it should have worked. I'll look into why it didn't, but thanks anyway.